# Cannot retrieve property from list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I've searched other questions but they don't seem to come across this issue.

This is the line of code I'm having trouble with:

```
tenderName = _vfpTenderTypes.Where(x => x.ID == tenderCode)
                            .Select(x => x.Name).ToString().Trim();
```

I have a list of objects (`_vfpTenderTypes`), each object has a few properties (`ID` & `Name` in this case). I want to retrieve the name of an object where the object `ID` matches a provided number (`tenderCode`).

When the code is run `tenderName` gets populated with the below text instead of the objects Name:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Models.TenderType,System.String]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Select is similar to the SQL select, you get a list of results back and not a single string.
Once you called .toString() you are getting the default Enumerable toString() and not just the result you wanted.
you can try using First or Single (in case it is unique) instead

```
tenderName = _vfpTenderTypes.First(x => x.ID == tenderCode).Name
```

Comment: All great answers and I actually learnt a few things using the advice from the others and looking up a LINQ. This answer seemed to solve my problem. Thanks a lot lads!

Answer (score 3):

Try one of the following based on your needs:

```
tenderName = _vfpTenderTypes.Where(x => x.ID == tenderCode).Select(x => x.Name.Trim());
```

Or this:

```
tenderName = _vfpTenderTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == tenderCode).Name.Trim();;
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `ToString()` from the end of the Linq query:

```
tenderName = _vfpTenderTypes.Where(x => x.ID == tenderCode)
                            .Select(x => x.Name.Trim());
```

***Additionally:***

You can use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` methods if there is only one item per `Id`:

```
tenderName = _vfpTenderTypes.Where(x => x.ID == tenderCode)
                            .Select(x => x.Name.Trim())
                            .Single();
```

Also, don't forget to check "Deferred Execeution in Linq" to learn how Linq works.

***Explanation:***

The reason of this output is that, you are calling `ToString()` method for the object which will return from `Select()` method, which is `WhereSelectListIterator` in this case.

```
public override IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TResult>(Func<TSource, TResult> selector) {
                return new WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<TSource, TResult>(source, predicate, selector);
            }
```

And `WhereSelectListIterator` has not any implementation for `ToString` method. And by default `ToString()` method returns the string representation of the type of the object instance:

```
  public virtual String ToString()
    {
        return GetType().ToString();
    }
```

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Models.TenderType,System.String]

Answer (score 2):

Because they can be chained, LINQ queries usually return `IEnumerable<TResult>`, to get a single result out of the initial collection
you have to use a method like `First` / `FirstOrDefault`, `Single` / `SingleOrDefault`:

```
var tenderName = _vfpTenderTypes.Where(x => x.ID == tenderCode)
                                .Select(x => x.Name.Trim()).SingleOrDefault();
```

Or:

```
var tenderName = _vfpTenderTypes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == tenderCode)
                                .Name.Trim();
```